# why jQuery/AJAX button don't working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a login form that is submitted with a jQuery AJAX request. I would like to use "button" be able to submit the form.but only "button" has no response to function (data)

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-signin">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="user" class="form-control loginid">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control loginpw">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Check" id="check" class="form-control ck_secure">
    <div class="captcha_block">
      <span id="captcha" class="captcha"></span>
      <a href="#" class="change" onclick="captchaCode()"> <img src="img/change.svg" alt="" class="photo04"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="login" id="login">Sign In</a> -->
    <!-- <input id="login" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Sign In"> -->
    <button id="login" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="login">Sign In</button>
```

**javascript:**

```
$("#login").click(function(){
        if($('#code').text() != $('#check').val()){
          alert('error');
          location.reload();
        }
        else{
          $.post('./process.php',
            {
              type : 'login',
              user : $('#user').val(),
              Passwd: $('#password').val()
            },
            function(data){
              alert(data);
              window.location.href = '../';
          });
        }
      });
```

**process.php:**

```
if($_POST['type'] == 'login'){
  $login_row = @mysql_fetch_assoc(@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE `user` = '".$_POST['user']."' AND `password` = '".$_POST['Passwd']."'"));
  if($login_row)
  {
   $_SESSION['user'] = $login_row['user_name'];
   echo 'welcome';
  }else
  {
   echo 'Incorrect username/password. please login again';
  }
 }
```

Comment: if you used ajax than no need form

Comment: @W.rc are you getting any error in console?

Comment: did you put `click` event handler inside `document.ready` ? If then also not working you should try event delegation.

Comment: Did you close your form?  Where is "#code"?

Comment: Please stop using this: `@mysql_fetch_assoc` and `@mysql_query`, the `@` symbol in php stands for 'ignore errors on this line' and it very bad to use. Use PDO or mysqli to not get deprecated errors for mysql

Comment: One also issue: add `type="button"` by default it will take as submit and as it is inside form that's why it's taking form submit.

Comment: do not trust users input.

Comment: do a `var_dump($_POST)` in process.php

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute `type=button` in your **Sign In** button like below.

```
<button type="button" id="login" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="login">Sign In</button>
```